# Turning higher spheres inside out

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I know that one can turn a sphere $S^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ inside-out having at each time an immersion of $S^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$. It is called Smale paradox. There is beautiful [animation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_w4HYXuo9M) about that.

Do you know if the same thing is possible for higher dimensional spheres? I mean, for a sphere $S^k$ in $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ for $k\geq 3$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hirsch extended Smale's theorem, his extension is called the [Smale Hirsch Theorem](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Hirsch-Smale_theory).  It applies to your question, and says that the map that sends an immersion $S^n \to \mathbb R^{n+1}$ to its derivative $TS^n \to T\mathbb R^{n+1}$. is a homotopy-equivalence.  Specifically, you consider the domain of this map to be the *space of immersions* of the sphere in Euclidean space, and the range to be the space of *bundle monomorphisms* from the tangent bundle of the sphere to the tangent bundle of Euclidean space.

Using the "cross product" construction you can convert between bundle monomorphisms $TS^n \to T\mathbb R^{n+1}$ and maps $S^n \to SO_{n+1}$. So the question of whether or not a sphere can be turned inside-out converts to whether or not these two maps $S^n \to SO_{n+1}$ (for the standard sphere and mirror reflection of the standard sphere) are homotopic.   So when $n=2$ we're done, since $\pi_2 SO_3 = 0$, but these maps can be non-trivial in higher dimensions.

First off, what are these elements of $\pi_n SO_{n+1}$?  They come from the standard immersion via this cross-product construction I mentioned. For the standard immersion of the sphere, the element of $\pi_n SO_{n+1}$ constructed is the trivial element.  How about for the mirror-reflected immersion?  If you think about it a little, you see it is a composite of two mirror reflections, first the mirror reflection across a fixed vector and 2nd the mirror reflection across the plane orthogonal to the point in $S^n$.  This map $S^n \to SO_{n+1}$ is known as the ["clutching map"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25659/tangent-sphere-bundle-over-sphere) for $TS^{n+1}$.

So the answer is, you can turn $S^n$ inside-out in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ if and only if the tangent bundle for the next higher-dimensional sphere $S^{n+1}$ is trivial.  Since $S^0$, $S^1$, $S^3$ and $S^7$ are the only spheres with trivial tangent bundles, that answers your question.  i.e. you can only turn $S^0$, $S^2$, and $S^6$ inside-out.

Comment: Isn't it possible that the clutching map could be non-trivial but still null-homotopic?  It feels like there's a step right at the end that I'm missing...

Comment: What do you mean by a non-trivial clutching map, that it describes a non-trivial vector bundle?  If so, the answer is no.  Bundles are classified by homotopy-classes of maps to Grassmannians, and this is one formulation of that equivalence.