# Does the function $f(x) = x^{\frac{4}{5}}$ have an angle at $x=0$?

Tags: calculus

Can we say that the function $f(x) = x^{\frac{4}{5}}$ has an angle at $x=0$? The graph of $f$ is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfv7l.jpg).

It's a multiple choices question which says "Which of the following statements is true for the given graph at $x=0$?" But all the other answers were wrong and I'm not sure if this one is right either.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cusp.html. Not sure about 'angle'. Would you mind sharing the other choices?

Comment: It is a "spike" (the proper term is a *cusp*) rather than an angle. Zoom in to see that it is very pointy. If you use Wolfram Alpha for plotting make sure that the scales on the x and y axes are the same.

Comment: Well it does have an angle, that angle is vertical and is shared by the two branches, so it's not unreasonable to say it has one. It doesn't have a slope.

Comment: @Shuri2060 sure. 1-it has a vertical asymptote at this point 2-the function is discontinuous at this point 3-f(0) is undefined 4-the function is differentiable at this point

Comment: The tangent of the slope of a curve is the derivative. $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}x^{\frac45}=\frac45x^{-\frac15}$. Does this approach anything as $x\to0$?

Comment: @JasonCarr my issue is the graph is uhh..kinda curved ? I dont really have a good enough english to describe it. but will it still count as an angle ?

Comment: For 1)  the function has a vertical tangent but not a vertical asymptote 2) the function is continuous at 0 3) f(0) is defined.  f(0)=0  4) the function is not differentiable at 0 as its derivative is undefined there.  Since the tangent line is vertical at x=0, it might be fair to say that the function makes a right angle *with the $x$-axis* at 0.

Comment: @Arthur  Yes.  Of course.  Thank you.  Edited appropriately.

Comment: @Arthur id like to be more specific myself, but thats literally all my book says. Option "A) it has an angle at the point." I'm pretty sure the other choices are wrong as the person above has shown but I dont get how this one is right either

Comment: @sharding4 oh. that makes sense, thanks.

Comment: @user46154 We can define it in the same way as the derivative. It doesn't particularly matter what the change in angle is, but we can define it instantaneously

Comment: Ahaha i'll be honest with you i didnt really understand at all, but thanks anyways. And from what I've studied so far seems like we say that derivatives that are perpendicular to the x-axis aren't defined from where I come from, so I guess I'll go with that too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like someone said, in a Cartesian plane, the slope of a right-angle against the x-axis isn't defined.
 Since that point is edge, the definition of differentiation depends on the problem. For example, in high school in my country it isn't defined because the limit value of the derivative is one-side.

However the edge isn't generally defined well in normal analysis. Advanced definition of tangent are given by geometrical discussion in [synthetic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_geometry). It is called [supported plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supporting_hyperplane) in convex geometry.

In topology or
differential geometry, [Ryan Budney](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/479417/268226) says it is decided whether it is possible to do sphere-inversion or circle-inversion ($0,2,6$ dimension) by existence of tangent bundles.